# Does $f$ have a local minimum?

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}, \ f(x,y)=e^{-x}+\alpha x^2 - y^2$. Does $f$ have a local minimum?

I want to prove this with derivative test but since there is $e^{-x}$, $f$ is always differentialble and  all the derivatives can never be zero for second, third derivative and so on, but except the first derivative $\begin{bmatrix}-e^{-x}+2\alpha x , -2y
\end{bmatrix}$, when $y=0$ and $2\alpha x= e^{-x}$.

Is there any other way that can be used to prove a function that has a local extrema?

Comment: I think you mean "$f(x,y)=e^{-x}+\alpha x^2-y^2$" ?

Comment: $\nabla f=0$ is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for an extreme point.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Ah yes thank you for your edition.

Comment: @K.defaoite yes, you're right. And I just thought out that we can prove the definitness of the hessian matrix of f. If it's positive definit or negative definit, then f has a local extrema, But since $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} e^{-x}+2\alpha  &0\\ 0 &-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}=-2<0$ so f has no local minimum. Am i right?